# How to keep track of bought items?

Tags: database-design

I want to keep track of how many times a user bought certain item. My `item` table currently looks like this:

```
ID  |  NAME  |  USER_ID  |
1   |  bread |  1        |
2   |  milk  |  1        |
3   |  bread |  2        |
```

What would be the recommended way of keeping track of bought items? Do I simply add a `counter` column and increase the value every time the item is bought?

```
ID  |  NAME  |  USER_ID  |  COUNTER  |
1   |  bread |  1        |  5        |
2   |  milk  |  1        |  1        |
3   |  bread |  2        |  3        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you ever need to know is the count, then by all means do that. Some applications might require another table listing each "purchase", for instance to be able to tell when each item was bought (in case the user buys the same item multiple times).

Also shouldn't that table rather be named `user_item` or something? The name `item` rather makes me think of a table that has information for each type of item (bread, milk) and has nothing to do with users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No need to track another info like date of purchase. The above is just an abstracted example, the real table name is different.

Comment: @finspin: All right. Naming is an important part of design though, so it's a good idea to use realistic names in examples too to avoid people like me complaining about them.

Comment: I see your point, haven't thought about the importance of using more realistic names in the examples. I'll know better next time :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend inserting new rows as more products are purchased rather than updating the counters of the products.

```
PID  |  NAME  | CREATED_ON
1    |  bread | 05-12-2012 9:45 AM
2    |  milk  | 05-12-2012 11:09 AM


ID  |  PID  |  USER_ID  | CREATED_ON
1   |  1    |   1       | 31-12-2012 10:05 AM
2   |  2    |   1       | 31-12-2012 10:05 AM
3   |  1    |   2       | 31-12-2012 11:05 AM
```

### Why ?

1. You can always sum upto a particular date (via filters) to the get
   count / implement a view to do the same.
2. It is better to insert a row rather than update existing count, both
   performance and transaction wise.
3. Finally, It is recommended you add a CREATED_ON column (default
   GETDATE()) as a record timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider spliting this into two tables: item and purchase

item:

```
ID  |  NAME  | 
1   |  bread | 
2   |  milk  |
```

purchase:

```
ID  |  ITEM_ID  |  USER_ID  | 
1   |    1      |     1     |
2   |    2      |     1     | 
3   |    1      |     2     |
```

And as for the number of purchases of each item by a specific user (to find number of "milks" bought by user # 1):

```
select count(*) from purchase where USER_ID = 1 and ITEM_ID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have 3 tables:

```
create table users (
  id number primary key,
  name varchar
)

create table items (
  id number primary key,
  description varchar,
  price double
)
```

and the 3rd table would be:

```
create table purchases (
  id number primary key,
  user_id number,
  item_id number,
  date timestamp, 
  foreign key user_id references users(id),
  foreign key item_id references items(id)
)
```

so you can check how many times a user bought an item by

```
select count(*) from purchases where user_id = 123 and item_id = 456;
```